# What is the area of the largest square inside an isosceles triangle if a vertex is placed at the midpoint of base?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics

$ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with base $AB$. Suppose that $AB = 5$ cm and the height of the triangle is $10$ cm. A square is placed inside the triangle $ABC$ so that one of its vertices is the midpoint of $AB$. Find the maximum area of the square in cm$^2$.

Can somebody help me with this question?
I have been trying to solve this but I couldn't find any way to do so. Thank you.

Comment: is $AB = AC$ or $AB=BC$ or $BC=AC$?

Comment: I am not sure if we should try both cases but I think since base AB is contrasted against height 10, so I think AC = BC?

Comment: do you know the answer? So that we can verify our answers.

Comment: There is no solution but the answer key given says 8

Comment: Hint: Imagine a small square balanced on the modpoint of the base so that one vertex is as given in the problem. How big can you make the square, and how do you orient it, before both adjacent vertices hit something that stops you?

Comment: @OscarLanzi even I've tried it: It does not give $8$

Comment: Doesn't the placement described by Oscar gives the side length of the square as 2? meaning area 4 as opposed to answer key's 8?

Comment: @JonathanRamachandran please add your attempt as described by Oscar Lanzi to your question to avoid further downvote on it or even closure.

Comment: Not the side length but the circumradius is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach.

---

First, try to find the largest square inside by experiments and observation, drawing the triangle and various squares in it.

Suppose $Q$ is the center of $AB$. Let the square be $PQRS$,

It looks that if the square is symmetric to line $CQ$ with $P$ on $CA$ and $R$ on $CB$, the square is as large as possible. Let $O$ be the center of the square. Then $C, O, Q$ are collinear. $OP\parallel QA$. We have
$$\frac{OP}{QA}=\frac{CO}{CQ}.$$
Let $OP=x$.
$$\frac{x}{\frac52}=\frac{10-x}{10}.$$
$$x=2.$$
Hence the area of $PQRS$ is $2x^2=8$.

---

Now our task is to prove $PQRS$ as described above does have the largest area among all possible squares.

Since $QP=2\sqrt2$, let us prove that any right isosceles inside the triangle with its right angle at $Q$ (which is a half of the square) must have its two equal sides no longer than $2\sqrt2$. Suppose the right isosceles is $\triangle XQY$. WLOG, suppose $\angle XQA\le 45^o$. Now we can prove that
$$QX\le2\sqrt2.$$

Comment: I had been drifting so close to the answer, but instead of taking $OP=x$ and using similarity, I used complicated trig! (+1)

Comment: Thank you so much Jack! I understand and I can complete the remaining details of the proof by myself. Peace!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is great to know you have completed the exercise.